# Resize rectangle with form Size in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is the following rectangle below:

[image]

When I resize the form, I need this rectangle to match the size of the form.

When changing the width of the rectangle, do not interfere with its visibility within the form.

I'm using the following:

Note:

I did the rectangle manually, but if you have rectangle ready, better yet!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    this.rectangles = new Dictionary<string, Rectangle>();
    this.sizeScreen = this.Size;
    this.sizeRectangles = new Size(8, 8);
    this.brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    FillLeft();
    FillRight();
    FillUp();
    FillDown();
}

private Size sizeScreen;
private Size sizeRectangles;
private SolidBrush brush;
private Dictionary<string, Rectangle> rectangles;
private void FillLeft()
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = this.sizeScreen.Height,
        Width = this.sizeRectangles.Width,
        X = 0,
        Y = this.sizeRectangles.Height
    };
    this.rectangles.Add("left", rectangle);
}
private void FillRight()
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = this.sizeScreen.Height,
        Width = this.sizeRectangles.Width,
        X = this.sizeScreen.Width - (this.sizeRectangles.Width * 5),
        Y = this.sizeRectangles.Height
    };
    this.rectangles.Add("right", rectangle);
}
private void FillUp()
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = this.sizeRectangles.Height,
        Width = this.sizeScreen.Width,
        X = 0,
        Y = this.sizeRectangles.Height
    };
    this.rectangles.Add("up", rectangle);
}
private void FillDown()
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = this.sizeRectangles.Height,
        Width = this.sizeScreen.Width,
        X = 0,
        Y = this.sizeScreen.Height - (this.sizeRectangles.Height * 11)
    };
    this.rectangles.Add("down", rectangle);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.rectangles.Count; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangles(this.brush, this.rectangles.Values.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I want to set the rectangle on the form when it is resized

This is the way I'm creating the rectangle, but it does not stay right on the screen, to resize it I do not know

Comment: If the rectangle is in/on the form, use the dock property?

Comment: How is that rectangle currently being displayed in your form?!

Comment: Is being displayed this way, it is like the panel, the panel has the fitting to fit in the form

Comment: I'm not using windows form controls, I want to create a rectangle manually to be resized with the form

Comment: How are you drawing/painting the rectangle on the form?

Comment: But, why do you have four rectagles there? Can't you draw a single rectangle around the client area and `Invalidate()` in the Form's `Resize` event?

Comment: They are rectangles in a line shape to fill each corner of the form with a line to become a rectangle, as in the picture above. That was my idea, but I do not know what to do if it is not so

Comment: Instead of 4 rectangles, you could use 1 rectangle and use e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, Rectangle) using a pen with the desired color and width.

Comment: Have you tried to draw a single rectangle using the Form's ClientRectangle as reference? In the Paint event, you can have just `using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 8)) { e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, this.ClientRectangle); }`

Comment: I committed a sin then ... but can you do the resizing that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would simplify what you are trying to do:

```
const int PenWidth = 10;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, PenWidth);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
}
```

You could even add a margin:

```
const int PenWidth = 10;
const int PenMargin = 10;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
    r.Inflate(-PenMargin, -PenMargin);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, PenWidth);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
}
```

To prevent traces (suggested by Wyck):

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I suggest using inset alignment for the pen.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-pen-width-and-alignment#to-create-an-inset-pen

Comment: When I resize, the form receives line traces

Comment: @sYsTeM calling `Invalidate` in response to `Resize` will fix the line traces.

Comment: Missed the traces.  Updated answer to include @Wyck suggestion and tested it this time :)

Comment: You need to Dispose of the Pen or declare it in a `using` block. Otherwise, you're leaking graphics resource each time the Paint event is raised (possibly thousands). + The standard Pen drawns **half** outside the bounds.: it should be `r.Inflate((int)-PenWidth / 2, (int)-PenWidth / 2);`.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `Resize` event and call `Invalidate` in the handler.  Create a Pen of the desired color and width and set its `Alignment` to `Inset`.  Handle the `Paint` event and in the handler call `DrawRectangle` passing in the `ClientRectangle` of the form.

Here is an example.

```
const float borderWidth = 8.0f;
Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.Red, borderWidth) { Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset };

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += Form2_Paint;
    this.Resize += Form2_Resize;
}

private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following fixes to the code:

- Set `ResizeRedraw` property of the form to `true`. It sets the underlying style for the form so by each resize it sends the paint message and you don't need to handle `Resize` event.
- Use `DrawRectangle` and draw using wide pen. So you don't need to fill multiple rectangles.
- Set the `PenAlignment` to `Inset`. So you don't need to calculate the location of rectangle.
- Do dispose the pen when you don't need it.

**Example**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ResizeRedraw = true;
}
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, PenWidth))
    {
        pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used this on my current project. when ever you resize the form, it will automatically resize all the object inside your form

i have class named clsResize and i call this on the form load.
1st you have to initialize the class inside the form then create 2 new method.

see example below

```
 public partial class frmNewForm : Form
    {

        clsResize _form_resize;
        public string selectedProd;



        public frmNewForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _form_resize = new clsResize(this);
            this.Load += _Load;
            this.Resize += _Resize;
        }
        private void _Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form_resize._get_initial_size();
        }
        private void _Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form_resize._resize();
        }
}
```

and here is the class that i used.

```
public class clsResize
{
    List<System.Drawing.Rectangle> _arr_control_storage = new List<System.Drawing.Rectangle>();
    private bool showRowHeader = false;
    public clsResize(Form _form_)
    {
        form = _form_; //the calling form
        _formSize = _form_.ClientSize; //Save initial form size
        _fontsize = _form_.Font.Size; //Font size
    }

    private float _fontsize  { get; set; }

    private System.Drawing.SizeF _formSize {get;set; }

    private Form form { get; set; }

    public void _get_initial_size() //get initial size//
    {
        var _controls = _get_all_controls(form);//call the enumerator
        foreach (Control control in _controls) //Loop through the controls
        {
            _arr_control_storage.Add(control.Bounds); //saves control bounds/dimension            
            //If you have datagridview
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                _dgv_Column_Adjust(((DataGridView)control), showRowHeader);
        }
    }

    public void _resize() //Set the resize
    {
        double _form_ratio_width = (double)form.ClientSize.Width /(double)_formSize.Width; //ratio could be greater or less than 1
        double _form_ratio_height = (double)form.ClientSize.Height / (double)_formSize.Height; // this one too
        var _controls = _get_all_controls(form); //reenumerate the control collection
        int _pos = -1;//do not change this value unless you know what you are doing

        try
        {
            foreach (Control control in _controls)
            {
                // do some math calc
                _pos += 1;//increment by 1;
                System.Drawing.Size _controlSize = new System.Drawing.Size((int)(_arr_control_storage[_pos].Width * _form_ratio_width),
                    (int)(_arr_control_storage[_pos].Height * _form_ratio_height)); //use for sizing

                System.Drawing.Point _controlposition = new System.Drawing.Point((int)
                (_arr_control_storage[_pos].X * _form_ratio_width), (int)(_arr_control_storage[_pos].Y * _form_ratio_height));//use for location

                //set bounds
                control.Bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(_controlposition, _controlSize); //Put together

                //Assuming you have a datagridview inside a form()
                //if you want to show the row header, replace the false statement of 
                //showRowHeader on top/public declaration to true;
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                    _dgv_Column_Adjust(((DataGridView)control), showRowHeader);


                //Font AutoSize
                control.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(form.Font.FontFamily,
                 (float)(((Convert.ToDouble(_fontsize) * _form_ratio_width) / 2) +
                  ((Convert.ToDouble(_fontsize) * _form_ratio_height) / 2)));

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return;
        }

    }

    private void _dgv_Column_Adjust(DataGridView dgv, bool _showRowHeader) //if you have Datagridview 
    //and want to resize the column base on its dimension.
    {
        int intRowHeader = 0;
        const int Hscrollbarwidth = 5;
        if (_showRowHeader)
            intRowHeader = dgv.RowHeadersWidth;
        else
            dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            if (dgv.Dock == DockStyle.Fill) //in case the datagridview is docked
                dgv.Columns[i].Width = ((dgv.Width - intRowHeader) / dgv.ColumnCount);
            else
                dgv.Columns[i].Width = ((dgv.Width - intRowHeader - Hscrollbarwidth) / dgv.ColumnCount);
        }
    } 




    private static IEnumerable<Control> _get_all_controls(Control c)
    {
        return c.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(item =>
            _get_all_controls(item)).Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>()).Where(control => 
            control.Name != string.Empty);
    }
}
```